# Send DeliverSMResp with logica smpp

Tags: java, smpp

How to send DeliverSMResp with Logica smpp? I see that class `Session` has `respond` method, but I dont understand how to get object of `DeliverSMResp` class from `PDU` received from SMSC.

```
public void handleEvent(ServerPDUEvent event) {
        PDU pdu = event.getPDU();
        System.out.println("PDU RECEIVED - " + pdu);
        if (pdu.isRequest()) {
            try{
                System.out.println("async request received, enqueuing " + pdu.debugString());
                session.respond(???????);
            }
```

I have assumption:

```
    DeliverSMResp deliverSMResp = new DeliverSMResp();
        deliverSMResp.setSequenceNumber(pdu.getSequenceNumber());
        starter.getSession().respond(deliverSMResp);
```

But i not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   DeliverSMResp deliverSMResp = new DeliverSMResp();
   deliverSMResp.setSequenceNumber(pdu.getSequenceNumber());
   starter.getSession().respond(deliverSMResp);
```

It works!

Comment: Hello I am actually in a similar situation. I assume that smsc calls back with the delivery_sm? I have set `   submitRequest.setRegisteredDelivery((byte)0x01)` . I know handleEvent is being called: `- async response received (submit_resp: (pdu: 18 80000004 0 2) 5 )` but I don't know how to get the actual delivery to handset

Comment: I already forgot and don't have access to my sources, but I assume that should be other response from SMSC which notifying client that sms was delivery. Also something in my mind says me that you should add something like "Delivery Notification Number" inside PDU before you sending it to SMSC, to let him know that you want to receive delivery notification.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it has not been able to help me much. Only method available there is `submitRequest.setRegisteredDelivery((byte)0x01)`